# Pandas GBQ and Python 3

Tags: pandas

Is the latest release of Pandas Google BigQuery (currently 0.16.2) module compatible with Python 3?  I know at one point it wasn't but not sure that update has been made?  If not, are there any plans to have Pandas GBQ modules support Python 3?

J

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of several new gbq features and an overhaul to the way testing was done [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#google-bigquery-enhancements). This should be pretty easy to add support (really just changing the minimum required api-client version).

[here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11094) is an issue to track this feature. pull-requests are welcome!